# QGIS leaflet webmap problem

Tags: qgis, leaflet

I created a webmap with qgis leaflet. It's working well on my pc. I uploaded the folder to my ftp server but on the internet it has no layers, only the osm basemap. I have no idea why.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Very vague. Post your code, especially any paths specified. Watch your browser's dev tools/console for any error messages. Those give good indications on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question.

One thing to try is looking at the console in your browser, see what errors are there.

You could post your code too, perhaps.

If you uploaded data too, then maybe it's having trouble finding the data.